# Firebase: Order query by a property and filter by a different property

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have something like this:

```
"records" : {
    "-KOHf6O3V35jqR4mENo1" : {
        "name" : "Foo",
        "type" : "One"
    },
    "-KOHf6O3V35jqR4mENo2" : {
        "name" : "Bar",
        "type" : "Two"
    },
    "-KOHf6O3V35jqR4mENo3" : {
        "name" : "Qux",
        "type" : "One"
    },
    "-KOHf6O3V35jqR4mENo4" : {
        "name" : "Baz",
        "type" : "One"
    },
}
```

**I want to get the first two records with type == "One" ordered by name.**

I can get the first two records ordered by name using:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("records");
ref.orderByChild("name").limitToFirst(2).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

I also can get all the records with type == "One":

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("records");
ref.orderByChild("type").equalTo("One").on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Is there any way to order the records by a property and filter them by another?
(The real record list would have thousands of records)

Comment: You can only have one `orderBy...()` call in a Firebase query. Sometimes you can get the result you want by having a single property that combines the values you want to order/filter on. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: @frank I think this is a different question/answer. Having a combined property may help for filtering by two properties (linked question), but not for sorting and filtering (this question). What parameter would you use in the equalTo function?

Comment: You'll need a combined property like `name_type: "Bar_One"` and then query `ref.orderBy("name_type").startAt("Bar_!").endAt("Bar_~")` or something along those lines.